# Model events not fire in laravel testing

Tags: laravel, testing, events

I'm writing some tests for my model when it was created/updated/deleted. When I test it manually, it worked. But when I test in test file, asserting a event dispatch always fail.

This is my test function:

```
public function test_booted_method_ran()
{
  $model = AcCard::factory()->create();
  $this->expectsEvents('eloquent.created: \App\Models\AcCard');
}
```

This test case always fails. I've tried to inspect `expectsEvents` and added `dd()` to check event list:

```
public function expectsEvents($events)
{
  $events = is_array($events) ? $events : func_get_args();
  $this->withoutEvents();
  $this->beforeApplicationDestroyed(function () use ($events) {
    $fired = $this->getFiredEvents($events);
    dd($fired); // Added this code line
    $this->assertEmpty(
      $eventsNotFired = array_diff($events, $fired),
      'These expected events were not fired: ['.implode(', ', $eventsNotFired).']'
    );
  });
  return $this;
}
```

And result is an empty array.

##### What I tried

- I tried to add this code lines above model creating

```
AcCard::flushEventListeners();
AcCard::boot();
AcCard::booted();
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you have had a chance to look at https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking#event-fake ?

Comment: @aliRaza Yes, it doesn't work. I've also checked dispatched event list in `assertDispatched` and it return an empty list too.